# Template partial specialization issues "template parameters not deducible in partial specialization"

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why there is a "template parameters not deducible in partial specialization". I could not find an answer to this with current answers.

Pre:

```
template<std::size_t, class T, class F>
struct IF {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T, class F>
struct IF<0, T, F>
{
    using type = F;
};
```

Actual Issue:

```
template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t z = x*y >
struct Selector
{
    using A = int; //simplified for questioning- uses x,y 
    using B = float;

    using type = typename IF<z, A, B>::type;
};


template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
using MyType = typename Selector<x, y>::type;


//Everything is good until here. 

template <typename T>
struct XTyp;
// struct XTyp : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
struct XTyp<MyType<x, y> > : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, x>
{
};
```

error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
struct XTyp<MyType<x, y> > : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, x>
note:         ‘x’
note:         ‘y’

See: https://godbolt.org/z/673f9WM3G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting the type alias, your partial specialization reads

```
template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
struct XTyp< typename Selector<x, y>::type > : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, x>
{
};
```

When the compiler needs to check whether this partial specialization should be chosen for a given specialization `XTyp<Arg>`, it has to check whether there are values `x` and `y`, such that `Arg` is the same as `Selector<x, y>::type`. But that is generally impossible, since each specialization of `Selector<x, y>` could have any type, including `Arg`, as `type`.

In terms of the language specification, everything left of a `::` is a *non-deduced* context in which template argument deduction cannot deduce template arguments.
But the `x` and `y` template arguments of the partial specialization must be deducible from `Arg` as if `XTyp<Arg>` was given as argument in a call to a function template with function parameter `XTyp< typename Selector<x, y>::type >`.

Since the template arguments of the partial specialization are never deducible, the compiler will reject the specialization outright.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. Althought it doesn't seem to work. https://godbolt.org/z/673f9WM3G

Comment: @Starfish I am not trying to fix your problem, I am just explaining why it doesn't work. From the code you have posted it is not clear to me what you intend the partial specialization to do, so I cannot give you any way to fix it.